# A custom labeled phone number

Tags: swift, contacts-framework

The `Contacts Framework` provides a kind of `phoneNumbers` label like this:

`CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone`, `CNLabelPhoneNumberMain`, `CNLabelPhoneNumberPager` and others.

```
for contact in self.contact.phoneNumbers {
            if contact.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone {
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
                break
            }
        }
```

But they're limited. There is no any options for a custom labeled `phoneNumbers`. Can I display a custom labeled `phoneNumbers` on a `Contacts Framework` ?

`
if !self.contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {

```
        for contact in self.contact.phoneNumbers {

           switch contact.label {
            case CNLabelHome:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelWork:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelOther:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberMain:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberPager:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberHomeFax:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            case CNLabelPhoneNumberOtherFax:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            default:
                self.phoneNumberTextField.text = (contact.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
                break
            }
       }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there is no direct way to get custom label numbers, so you can do like this to get custom label numbers :-

```
if !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
  for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
      // This return All the phone Numbers
      if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone {
          //iPhone number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile {
          //Mobile phone number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMain {
          //Main phone number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberHomeFax {
          //Home fax number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax {
          //Work fax number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberOtherFax {
        //Other fax number.
      } else if number.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberPager {
        //Pager phone number.
     } else {
        // Custome Phone Number
        // number.label -> to get custome label name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great! But I don't understand. How to get a custom label? Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean custom label name ?

Comment: Yes! A custom label name

Comment: print ,   number.label the you can get the label name :)

Comment: It seems to works perfectly! But this code only takes a one custom label. Users may have one or more custom labeled contacts.

Comment: I've edited my question. So you can find all of the codes from there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, Ill go through with this :)

Comment: Maybe I have missed a break statement.

Comment: Yeah this is a for loop so its basically show last value in text feild. So if you want to take all the values just initialise string variable and append out put each times it iterate through  the for loop :)

Comment: This might be better expressed as a `switch`.

Comment: Did you mean a switch statement?

Comment: Dear @sschale! A  `Switch` statement doesn't necessary anymore! I don't know why? It's still contains a single value. I've added some codes and edited my question's details too.

Answer (score 1):

The `label` property of a `CNLabeledValue` is actually a string. It may hold a value such as `Dad` or `Apartment`, or in the case of the predefined label constants it equals `_$!<Main>!$_` or `_$!<Home>!$_`, etc. So if your given `label` doesn't match any of your predefined constants then display the string as is, since that is likely a custom label.